# NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8101/ When Unity Building on Mac When Running on Home Network

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

The following error is occurring when I try to run a scene on Unity 2021.3.16 . Interestingly, this only happens when I try running it on my home wifi. It works fine when connected to my phone's hotspot (also AT&T), when at my schools wifi or other wifis, and works as expected when not connected to wifi at all. What could be the issue here.

xrai WebViewer CallOnError[Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.189:8101/, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <0F16D8B4-99E1-400C-8720-2DE7B17001CE>.<809>, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., _WKRecoveryAttempterErrorKey=<WKReloadFrameErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x2c8f87c40>, networkTaskDescription=LocalDataTask <0F16D8B4-99E1-400C-8720-2DE7B17001CE>.<809>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.189:8101/, NSUnderlyingError=0x32e9f3f40 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}}]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this problem was caused by the C# line `_listener.Prefixes.Add($"http://+:{AppState.WebServerPort}/");`, which uses the + symbol as a wildcard to bind the listener to all available network interfaces on the machine, both IPv4 and IPv6. This was an issue as IPv6 on my network wasn't working as expected, something I checked with the following:

```
    if ping6 -c 2 -t 2 2001:4860:4860::8888 > /dev/null; then
        echo "IPv6 connectivity: OK"
        return 0
    else
        echo "IPv6 connectivity: Failed"
        return 1
    fi
```